# Are these MLE estimates biased?

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, optimization, weibull-distribution

It was my understanding that MLE estimates were asymptotically unbiased. The following simulation therefore confuses me. Can anyone help me with my understanding here?

I estimate the parameters of 50 random Weibulls that I've simulated with shape = scale = 1 (using the Wikipedia/R parameterisation)

After lots of simulations, we should* get a distribution of parameter estimates, the median of which equals the simulated values.

The result is that the median of the estimates are significantly different from the simulated parameters:

```
         shape     scale
est   1.018636 0.9954484
2.5%  1.015124 0.9919716
97.5% 1.021469 0.9984734
```

I expect I may be wrong at the "should*" above. If so, what is correct?

---

The R code is below:

I am simulating using `rweibull()` and estimating parameters using `mle()` in the core stats4 package and also `fitdist()` in the fitdistrplus. I am using the correct estimates as the starting parameters, so there shouldn't be any optimisation issues here. (?)

```
# fitdistrplus::fitdist() fitting
res <- replicate(1e4,
                 fitdist(
                   rweibull(50,shape=1,scale=1),
                   distr="weibull",
                   start=list(shape=1,scale=1)
                 )$est
)

# stats4::mle() fitting
res <- replicate(1e4,{
  y <- rweibull(50,shape=1,scale=1)
  nll <- function(shape,scale) -sum(dweibull(y,shape,scale,log=TRUE))
  res <- stats4::mle(
    nll,
    start=list(shape=1,scale=1)
  )@coef
})

# calculate median of the simulated estimates and its bootstrapped confidence interval
apply(res,1,function(x){
  c(est=median(x),
    quantile(
      replicate(1e3,
                median(sample(x,replace=TRUE))
                ),
      c(0.025,0.975)
      )
    )
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Increase the sample size from fifty & the averages of your parameter estimates over many simulations should get closer still to the true ones—that's what *asymptotically* unbiased means.

[As @Joe's pointed out, bias (at least "bias" without further qualification—there is such a thing as median-unbiasedness) is the expected difference between the true value & its estimate, so you should be looking at the means rather than the medians in your simulations, if it's this you want to assess.]

Comment: So you're saying that even if I had infinite simulations, but still a finite sample size, it would always be biased?

I was originally interpreting asymptotically as meaning "If I simulate enough, it will eventually match the original parameters"

Comment: That's right. In statistics "asymptotically" means "as the sample size goes to infinity" unless otherwise qualified. You might also be interested in looking at the variance of your estimates, & hence the overall mean-square error.

Comment: OK, so are there ways of correcting this consistent bias for the finite sample size case, or is there a general statistical topic name for this? Thanks

Comment: What makes you think the median of the shapes will be equal to the shape?  That doesn't mean that the method is biased for finite samples...  What's the sampling distribution of the shape parameter?

Comment: For the general ideas read the chapter on point estimation in a theoretical statistics book. Unbiased estimates sound good but ...(1) They may have higher variance; enough to make the overall MSE higher. (2) Unlike MLEs, they're not in general invariant to reparameterization. So you can get a unbiased estimator of the scale parameter for your Weibull distribution, but its reciprocal won't be an unbiased estimator of the rate. (3) If you choose an estimate that isn't the MLE, your observations were *less* probable (roughly speaking) if that estimate were right than if the MLE were.

Comment: @Joe: Good point - bias is defined in terms of the expected value of the sample estimate. All the same the asymptotic convergence at issue here is to a normal distribution whose mean & median coincide at the true value of the parameter.

Comment: @Scortchi It will converge to the Normal asymptotically... but for the finite sampling distribution of the parameter, I don't see any reason to expect that the mean and median will be equal.

Comment: @Joe: You're right, but I'm not sure what you're getting at. Asymptotically, the MLE's median-unbiased & mean-unbiased, but that doesn't imply the MLE for a finite sample is either mean- or median-unbiased, which was the confusion that prompted the OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has a section on finite-sample bias correction for MLEs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Higher-order_properties